# Hotmail Alerts using Live API

Tags: c#, live, email, hotmail

Iam looking to write a C# application to alert the user when he gets an email on his hotmail account.
I have already gone through

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/httpmail.aspx

But seems that Microsoft has discontinued it now.
http://www.eweek.com/article2/0,1759,1652391,00.asp

I looked to the Live SDK but couldn't find any mail related API's in it , can anybody suggest where exactly I should look for? I am a passionate researcher , just a small pointer would be enough for me.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You state you want to write the application; I assume you already did some research on the matter in that case? If so, please clarify your question and state the problems you are facing so people can help you. This is not a linkdump.

Comment: Hi Aron, I have elaborated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for something similar to what MSN Messenger does when you get a new message (at least it works like that for me), then you could try a packet sniffer to see what packets are coming and going when the popup occurs.

Comment: could you suggest some nice packet sniffers and how could I implement the same in C#?

Answer (score 0):

- POP3 is available for all users
- IMAP is only available to Premium users.
- HttpMail is only avaliable to Premium users. (it's also poorly documented)

I have [a similar question, but for Java,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965460/access-hotmail-unread-mail-count-via-java) which may or may not be useful.